# how to use google search in googleweblight

Tags: google-chrome, googleweblight

I'm trying to browse this url: googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://www.google.com
but I'm not able to, since I got:

```
Transcoding test failed:
This page could not be transcoded due to technical issues.
```

The problem is that I need to copy paste every search result I get from google search page into `googleweblight.com/?lite_url=[here]`

Why am I not able to use googleweblight for google? How can I make my urls go to googleweblight version directly, without copy and paste and not using a device emulator in user agent?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem

Comment: nope. no progress there.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox, I am using the [UAControl add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/uacontrol/) to change my browser's User-Agent to Mobile Safari, and it gives me the mobile version of Google Search, which by default has all search result URLs pointing via GoogleWebLight.

In fact, since I didn't want the URLs to be redirected via GoogleWebLight as such, I had to write a [GreaseMonkey script](https://github.com/janakaud/js-on-firefox/blob/master/greasemonkey/GoogleSearch/GoogleSearch.user.js) to convert them back to 'regular' (direct) URLs. Maybe you can modify it to do the opposite on the Google Search page, if you're not comfortable with the User-Agent switch approach. I believe you can utilize something like [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) if you're on a different browser such as Google Chrome.